# EJB 2.0 Object Handles

Tags: java, ejb

How EJB 2.0 Object handles (retrieved from getHandle() )help resuming after a disconnect from the server? When a disconnect happens, the EJB Object skeleton on the server side will be garbage collected and so will be the bean instance. Is the conversational state saved in the stub on the client which is obtained from getHandle()?

Answer (score 0):

javax.ejb.Handle is ultimately just a wrapper around an RMI stub that knows how to reconnect to the server's ORB when deserialized.  (Normally, a deserialized stub will throw an error about a "missing delegate" because it has not been reconnected to an ORB).

For stateless and entity beans, there is no conversational state, so I assume you're asking about stateful beans.  For stateful beans, conversational state is always stored on the server, not the client.  Conversational state will not be saved, so the handle will only be valid until the instance is timed out on the server.